# Any reason why latency in updating timelineitem to my glass device?

Tags: google-mirror-api

i see latency issue - when i send a timelineitem from my glassware app, it takes a long time to appear on glass device. 
I see the item in developer playground (https://developers.google.com/glass/playground)
Is it isolated issue on my WiFi (unlikely)? or some optimization done at Mirror server which queues timelineitems and sending in a specific interval to glass device?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow may not be the best place for this question since your question is about using Glass. You probably want to direct this question to the Glass support team: https://www.google.com/glass/help/

Comment: Sorry about the original question - i have talked to glass support, but i could not get an answer, that's why i posted here. Never mind. Regarding latency, I tried from my home network, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more investigation (In my case, i have setup private network inside enterprise network), i found out that some of the ports are blocked by firewall settings for incoming traffic from outside network, so glass device was not getting notifications from the Mirror Server.
It is possible either Channel API or XMPP is used in receiving notification messages from Mirror server to Glass. Those ports might have blocked by my firewall settings. I ran wireshark, still it is not clear which protocol or port is used in receiving notifications. 
Also it is possible that glass device could get (HTTP GET) newly available cards from the mirror server by polling on specific time interval or other cases(changing WIFI network, etc).
I called Glass help, i could not get any feedback. 
I would really appreciate if someone (from Google) could shed some light (port and protocol details) on how Glass gets notification from mirror server when new timeline card is available.

**This is a known issue:**
https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=185

Answer (score -1):

Issue has been fixed by updating to XE10.

Comment: Two particular issues related to this symptom have been fixed.  Not all.  It is still very much an issue.